# Getting issue with placement new and delete operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator, delete-operator

I have written the following code for placement new and delete operator functions. Can you please tell the issue with the code below.

```
// new_operator.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Mem
{
public:
    void* alloc(size_t sz) { return malloc(sz); }
    void dealloc(void* ptr) { free(ptr); }
};

class Object
{
public:
    Object() { cout << "In Constructor Object()" << this << endl; }
    ~Object() { cout << "In Destuctor ~Object()" << endl; }
    void* operator new(size_t sz, Mem* handle)
    {
        Object* x1 = (Object*)handle->alloc(sz);
        return x1;
    }
    void operator delete(void* ptr, Mem* handle)
    {
        cout << "Here\n";
        ((Object*)(ptr))->~Object();
        handle->dealloc(ptr);
    }
};
int main()
{
    Mem* memory = new Mem;
    Object* obj = new (memory) Object;
    cout << "Obj is " << obj << endl;
    delete (obj, memory);
    delete memory;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting runtime crashes at the time when delete operator function starts executing. Can anyone please tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What do you believe this does? `(obj, memory)`

Comment: Why are you storing an `Object` in the space allocated for a `Mem`?

Comment: In `delete (obj, memory);` , you are invoking the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), so that statement is effectively the same as `delete memory;` which are you also calling immediately afterwards. So you are `delete`ing the same `memory` twice. Also, you can't `delete` an object created with `placement-new`, since it will try to deallocate memory that wasn't allocated with `new`.

Comment: op> You are using this wrong. Placement new and/or new operator are not intended to replace proper use of allocators, which seems to be what you actually want. (for reference, the operator delete you wrote is only called if the new expression fails, to free memory, it won't be called on a delete, ever).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The `operator new` function allocates bytes, not objects.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, the member version of `operator new` still allocates raw bytes. It is not supposed to constructs any class objects. `malloc` is just fine.

Comment: I stand corrected. Raw bytes is fine. The construction of `Object` using [new expression (placement_new)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) took a bit of digesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Placement delete is called to free memory when a constructor called from placement new fails. You are not supposed to call any destructors from any version of `operator delete`, because `operator delete` frees memory that is left after an object that used to reside there is destroyed (or was never constructed to begin with).
2. The only way to explicitly call a placement operator delete is to spell out two words `operator delete`, thus making a function-call-expression. You cannot invoke it from a delete-expression (there is no placement-delete-expression syntax). In your case, you would need to use a qualified name: `Object::operator delete`. Note that if you remove the explicit destructor call from `Object::operator delete`, as you should because of the above, the destructor will not be called. There is no way to both invoke the destructor and free the memory in a single call to a placement delete. The easiest way to handle this is to create and use a non-static member function, say `void Object::destroy(Mem*)`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> delete (obj, memory);
> ```

On this line, you delete only `memory`, not `obj`. The left hand operand of comma operator is discarded. Since the expression `obj` has no side-effects, this is probably a mistake.

> ```
> delete memory;
> ```

On this line, you delete `memory` again. This results in undefined behaviour.

Note that you never destroy the dynamic `Object` that you created. The custom placement delete overload will only be called in case the placement new throws an exception. In other cases, your malloc will leak.